# How to update data after insert?

Tags: php, mysql

mysql_query("INSERT INTO withdraw (username,amount,date) SELECT username,amount,NOW() FROM accounts WHERE username='$username'  UPDATE accounts SET amount =0  WHERE username = '$user'")

i want to update data after insert but this query not working

Comment: Please use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: better to test on mysql console or through phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all the columns you need to insert in the select-part

```
INSERT INTO withdraw (username, amount, some_date) 
            SELECT    username, amount, now() 
              FROM accounts 
             WHERE username='$username';
```

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO withdraw (username,amount,date) SELECT username,amount,NOW() FROM accounts WHERE username='$username'  UPDATE accounts SET amount =0  WHERE username = '$user'")                   i want to update data after insert

Comment: I'm not aware of if this is possible using mysql_query but what you need to do is those two statements in one transaction.

Comment: amount=0 after transfer amount from one table to another table

Answer (score 0):

This is how the syntax should be -

```
INSERT INTO Table2
(client_last_name, client_first_name, taskDescription, category)
(SELECT clientLastName, clientFirstName, incidentDescription, category
FROM Table1
WHERE info_field IS NOT NULL)
```

**ADVICE:** Avoid using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated in recent PHP versions. Learn `mysqli prepared statement` or `PDO` and start implementing.

Comment: BUT I WANT TO INSERT CURRENT DATE

Comment: MY QUERY WORK PERFECTLY WITHOUT NOW()

Comment: WHEN I'M ADDING NOW() THEN QUERY NOT WORKING

Comment: @SyedMuzzammilMian Please, no caps. And stop spamming, you could have put all that in one comment.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can split your statement into two parts. Assuming that you want to make NOW() to be current date in all inserted rows (I write as in SQL Server because I can't write in MySQL, if you can please try to convert it into MySQL):

```
@date=NOW();
INSERT INTO withdraw (username,amount) SELECT username,amount FROM account WHERE
username=@username;
UPDATE withdraw
SET date=@DATE where ID=@@IDENTITY
```

If your table has IDENTITY ID column. In MySQL it is auto increment and an appropriate function is `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (selects last inserted ID in MySQL, you can google for more information)

Comment: Unless username is the primary key the update will not update all of the rows inserted, not even if there was that kind of @@IDENTITY in MySQL.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW() in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\balance.php on line 151